# Does the size of props affect the react component performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a parent component which is receiving some data (a big object) by routing (via history.push), now i have to send that data to two child components.
Now i can send that big object to both two child components and do two calculations (independent of each other) in respective child components, or i can do two calculations in parent component and then send calculated values to child components, resulting in decreased size of props.
Do small props (is size) give any performance benefits (regardless of my current scenario)?

Is there any testing library for measuring and quantifying the performance in both the scenarios, such as fast render, low ram consumption, etc.?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference because props, no matter what their size, are passed to child components as reference, not as copy

Comment: Most browsers have dev tools built-in that can do all kinds of performance audits and recording. Try to become familiar with them.

Comment: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say **NO**; the big object you have in the parent component is somewhere in the `heap` (javascript's ram, kinda) and it exists there, taking up memory sapce; when you pass it down to the child you probably passing its reference; child component will do the calculation in the same place in the `heap` that the parent component does;

If it was a microservice we could consider that because services don't use shared memory and only communicating through message passing, therefore the message size between services would actually increase the computation time in the other service, but a javascript application(i.e. a react app) is a monolith architecture, there is a shared memory available to every part of the program; hence it doesn't make sense; because your application have some necessary complexity to do its job( including memory and time consumption). so if that calculation is neccessary it doesn't matter where you do it, in the parent or in the children, it must be done somewhere at the end of the day; you don't want to the same calculation over and over, creating redundancy and waste resources; as an example if you should do `10` neccessary calculation, you may do it like `10 + 0` or `2 + 8` or `5 + 5`. you may chunk it, but in the end; its just ten.